# How NodeJS event loop works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

For the below code,

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.watch('target.txt', function(event, fileName){
    console.log('Event: ' + event + ', for file: ' + fileName);
    });

Console.log('Now watching target.txt');
```

As per the below architecture,

1) `fs.watch()` will invoke `libuv`. `libuv` will launch a thread to track `change` event on `target.txt`. The result from `libuv` will go to `v8` and again through `NodeJS Bindings` in the form of callback with a buffer having data.

2) `libuv` adds `change` event in Event queue. As the event loop picks the `change` event, corresponding call back is executed in `v8` run time.

### [image]

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I do not understand down-voters. The op misunderstands Node, but this is a common misunderstanding, so this question will actually prove to be helpful to many people who begin to use NodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you misunderstand it. NodeJS does not have threads, it is single-threaded instead, using the [Observer Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer). The event loop waits for events to occur (to observe an event). When an event is occurred, then it calls its handler. The illusion of multi-threaded approach comes from the fact that Node frequently uses async events, defining callback functions to be executed when a given task is finished. Read more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_event_loop.htm).

Comment: @overexchange, "Node js is a single threaded application but it support concurrency via concept of event and callbacks." http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_event_loop.htm

Comment: Ok, I wrote python code, similar to [this](https://github.com/shamhub/Design_pattern/tree/master/EventHandling-Observer_pattern).

Comment: Did this answer help you in solving your problem?

Comment: As you said: *it is single-threaded instead, using the Observer Pattern.*. Can you verify [this](https://github.com/shamhub/Design_pattern/tree/master/EventHandling-Observer_pattern) code that implements it?

Comment: I am not a Python expert, but the code seems to be a nice implementation at first sight.

Comment: How does the task scheduler know that task is finished? assuming task can be any call on wire

Comment: Supposedly there is a task Queue and whenever a new task is scheduled, it is pushed into the queue, while when it is executed, it is popped from the Queue. So the part which executes the tasks needs to remove the task being executed from the Queue.

Comment: No, this model is not multithreaded. It periodically checks whether there is a task to be executed and if so, it executes. No threads, nothing like that, just an infinite cycle of a task manager.

Comment: When it executes the task, what happens when task goes on IO wait? How task scheduler gets its control back? Because this is single threaded

Comment: NodeJS has an event loop for this purpose, kindly read this article for more information: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/